# FCKEditorAPI not defined until the page loads

Tags: fckeditor

I am trying to use

```
alert(FCKeditorAPI.GetInstance("FCKeditor1").GetXHTML());
```

in firebug output console and getting Reference "FCKeditorAPI is not defined". Could you please let me know how to resolve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: if you got answer. Can you share it please.

Answer (score 0):

Since your post is quite recent, I suppose you are using FCKeditor version 3.

If so, to get the editor instance, you should use:

```
CKEDITOR.instances["FCKeditor1"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, by binding this to some event

```
if( typeof( FCKeditorAPI ) !== "undefined" ) 
  FCKeditorAPI.GetInstance("FCKeditor1").GetXHTML()
```